# How can a JavaScript app detect if a Leap Motion device is connected

Tags: javascript, leap-motion

The subject says it all:

How can a JavaScript app detect if a Leap Motion device is connected.

It's so easy to move the Leap Motion devices from one computer to another, how can a JavaScript app detect if there is a device currently connected to the computer?

**Update 2013-08-08**

I have marked this question as answered because as Dmitry's work shows there is - as of this writing - no simple way for a JavaScript app to know if a Leap Motion device is connected at the load time of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what operating system API and drivers you have available. When a device is connected to a computer an operating system can detect a device connected to one of its sockets (using IRQ, polling etc.). You can then use driver or OS API (if it supports this kind of devices natively) to check a state of the device. Since this is usually done using a more low-level programming language like C++, C or even the assembly language (javascript is not suitable for several reasons) you should check your javascript API reference (not sure if you use browser API, Win8 API or something else) and see if there are any functions related.

Update: The API link you sent seems to be quite vague on that. However I figured out that it establishes a WebSocket connection to a localhost under the hood. The `Controller.connect()` function is really a procedure (does not return anything). But I found a more useful link (getting started: http://js.leapmotion.com/start) there is a description of different events that they provide including the following:

- deviceConnected - A Leap device has been connected
- deviceDisconnected - A Leap device has been disconnected

You can use a callback instead of a predicate in this case:

```
function doMyOwnStuff()
{
      console.log( "O_o" );
}

var controller = new Leap.Controller();

controller.on('deviceConnected', function() {
  console.log("A Leap device has been connected.");
  doMyOwnStuff();
});

controller.on('deviceDisconnected', function() {
  console.log("A Leap device has been disconnected.");
});

//should probably fire a 'deviceConnected'
controller.connect();
```

I hope it helps because I don't have the hardware to test.

Comment: Thanks, @Dmitry. The apps I build for the Leap Motion device are web apps in JavaScript. These have no direct access to the Client OS.

The Leap Motion API documentaion is here: http://js.leapmotion.com/api/v0.2.0-beta6/docs
 

There seems to be no connected true/false call in there.

Comment: @Dimitry

Many thanks. Your code works well ( was just missing the closing parens).


Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/theo/5x3DA/


Your code works fine to indicate if a device is connected or disconnected after you load the page.

But it does not indicate whether a device is already connected or not at the time you load the page.

So you should be able to test this case even without the device - because that is the case I would like to identify...

Comment: @Theo, since I can't find anything decent in the API I have a different solution: you can monitor the status after the you load the page and then use it afterwards http://pastebin.com/nEKjcShN. Try this - I still can't check because it doesn't connect to the local server (well, I didn't install it :) ). There should be a possibility to check it through connection objects but I couldn't find how yet.

Comment: @Dimitry, I tried your suggestion and no luck. See all the details on GitHub: https://github.com/jaanga/gestification/tree/gh-pages/motion-device-detector.  I think the answer is that - as of this writing - there is no simple `.isConnected` solution available for the Leap Motion device. Thank you very much for your good work. I wll mark the question as answered/

Answer (score 0):

To learn about integrate Leap with Web App, I decompiled New York Times Reader for Leap Motion.

Regarding its implementation (built.js), following code may help. (based on Backbone.js)

var LeapController = new Leap.Controller({enableGestures: true});

```
    window.L = LeapController;

    LeapController.on('deviceConnected', function () {
        console.log('deviceConnected', arguments);
        // in the example code, this fires when the app starts.
        // in our app, it only fires when the device is reconnected after having been connected when the app was started.
        dispatch.trigger('LeapControl:reconnect');
    });

    LeapController.on('ready', function () {
        // this fires when the app is ready.
        dispatch.trigger('LeapControl:reconnect');
    });

    LeapController.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('device is connected');
        // this fires when no device is plugged in. wtf.
    });

    LeapController.connection.on('deviceConnect', function () {
        console.log('deviceConnect');
        // this fires when the device is changes state from plugged in to ungplugged and vice versa.
    });

    LeapController.on('deviceDisconnected', function () {
        console.log('deviceDisconnected', arguments);
        dispatch.trigger('LeapControl:disconnect');
    });
```

Obviously developers of NYTimes Reader have already discovered as well that it would be not easy to detect if Leap Controller was already connected before the app loaded. ("wtf", haha....)

And part of code that defined the behavior of LeapControl:disconnect/reconnect event, intelligible:

```
newNews.views.Disconnected = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#disconnection-box'),
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this);
    },
    open: function () {
        this.listenTo(dispatch, 'LeapControl:disconnect', this.show);
        this.listenTo(dispatch, 'LeapControl:reconnect', this.hide);
        return this;
    }, ........
```

Thus, when LeapControl:reconnect was triggered, a pop-up saying that "leap motion controller not detected" would hide.

Upon debugging, when leap motion was already plugged in before launching the app, the events would be triggered in following order, and that ensures the correct detection:

1. LeapController.on('connect', function () {
               console.log('device is connected');
           });
2. LeapController.on('ready', function () {
               dispatch.trigger('LeapControl:reconnect');
           });

Simultaneously, if not plugged in beforehand, this and only this will be triggered:

1. LeapController.on('connect', function () {
               console.log('device is connected');
           });

As a conclusion, we may use 'ready' event to deal with this scenario. HTH